# How to autoscroll based on id or class value using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, autoscroll

The html code `<div id="sim"></div>` and related CSS code below

```
#sim{
    width:800px;
    height:300px;
    border:solid 1px #2e2e2e;
    color:#2e2e2e;
    padding:5px;
overflow:auto;
border:9px outset #0ADA0A;
margin-top:1em;
font-size:16pt;
}
```

its used for reading simulation. if i will enter more than 2000 words into the box, the box changes with scroll bar. when i press the button, it will reading with highlighted on text.

But, the border size is `width:800px; height:300px;`, the words overflow into the box, the text has been hidden highlighting .

https://jsfiddle.net/8Lwm6gh1/40/

How can i see the reading with auto focus and auto scroll using JS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I might have misunderstood what you were trying to achieve, but the way I comprehended it you wanted the view to scroll so that the current word always was shown in the div.

In order to keep track of the elements in the view, I used a `<span>` for each word, and attached a class `read` on all words that have been read. That way, you can use jQuery to select the next word by having the following selector:

```
var unread = $('span:not(.read):first');
```

I altered the code you wrote, and made it work. You also never stop the timeout, so I added a `clearTimeout()`-function.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8Lwm6gh1/87/)

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, you can use [**Element.scrollIntoView()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView), and add this line at the end of your timeout:

```
$('#sim b:last')[0].scrollIntoView(false);
```

[**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/g9zsa86n/)